# How to configure IIS when installed on a box already running a JBoss web server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, jboss

I have a Windows Server 2008 SP2 64-bit server currently running the JBoss 4.2.1 web server, which is hosting an Adobe LiveCycle ES2 server, on port 8080.

Have been asked to setup IIS on that box to act as an intermediary between the Java based LiveCycle and a WCF service on a remote server.

As long as the two web servers are listening on separate ports (IIS on 80 and JBoss on 8080) is there any additional configuration likely to be needed to prevent the two clashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will coexist just fine assuming that their working and installation directories do not overlap.